# Como adicionar o status inválido em campos input html?

Tags: php, javascript, html5

Eu estou a fazer validações no banco de dados antes do usuário enviar o formulário, porém, digamos que o e-mail digitado já exista no banco de dados, como eu poderia marcar o campo `input` como inválido para que o usuário não possa enviar caso não seja alterado o valor atual do `input`?

**Obs:** 
Eu digo por inválido a validação da propria API HTML, por exemplo um campo `input` não correspondendo ao `pattern=""`.

[image: validação usando API HTML]

Comment: no back php e front html+js.

Comment: Embora as respostas sejam claras quanto as sugestões e recomendações, o problema não esta relacionado a saber se já existe, o problema é somente marcar o campo como inválido como por exemplo na imagem que upei.

Answer (score 3):

**Não é possível** checar os emails no banco só usando a "API do HTML" (`pattern=""`), em WEB a comunicação é toda feita via HTTP, então precisa de uma requisição.

Será necessário fazer isto usando Ajax por exemplo:

```
function validateEmail(field)
{
    //Se o campo estiver vazio ou desabilitado então não valida
    if (field.value == "" || field.disabled) return;

    field.disabled = true;

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;

    xhr.open("GET", "checkEmail.php?email=" + encodeURIComponent(emailField.value), true);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            if (xhr.status == 200) {
               if (xhr.responseText == 'disponivel') {
                   alert('Validou');
               } else {
                   alert('Não validou');
               }
            } else {
                alert('Erro HTTP: ' + xhr.status);
            }
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.send(null);
}
```

No HTML deve ser algo como:

```html
<form>
    <input type="email" pattern="[^@]@[^@]$" required onblur="validateEmail(this)">
    <button>Cadastrar</button>
</form>
```

No php (parece que é o que você usa) bastaria retornar uma string como 'disponivel' acaso o email **não exista** no banco, ou retornar qualquer outra coisa acaso já exista, um exemplo com mysqli:

**checkEmail.php**

```
<?php
if (empty($_GET['email'])) {
    die('email vazio');
}

$email = $_GET['email'];

if (!preg_match('#^[^@]+[@][@]+$#', $email)) {
    die('formato inválido');
}

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

$query = 'SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM tabela WHERE email=?';

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);

$stmt->bind_param('s', $email);

$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result($total);

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    if ($total > 0) {
        echo 'já cadastrado';
    } else {
        echo 'disponivel';
    }
}
```

Comment: É quase isso, na verdade o que eu preciso esta justamente a partir desse ponto que você respondeu, se por exemplo, eu sei que o e-mail 'já esta cadastrado', eu quero marcar o campo como inválido, para que o usuário não possa enviar o formulário.

Answer (score 1):

Fiz um exemplo para checar se o que o usuário já digitou é igual ao valor do banco.

```js
$.getJSON('emailbdvalue.php', function (data) {
   email = data.dado.email;  // aqui tráz o email cadastrado no banco

   $("#email").on("blur", function() { // função quando o usuário tira o foco do input
   valida = $(this).val(); // pega o que foi digitado pelo usuário

       if(valida != email || valida == "") {  
          $("#email").prop("disabled", false);
       }
       else {
       $("#email").prop("disabled", true);
       }
   })
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
E-mail:
<input type="email" id="email">
```

Comment: urldobanco? Será que não esta a fazer confusão?

Comment: Ele não quer checar se o que o usuário digitou no input não é igual ao que está no banco?

Comment: Estou bem certo que banco de dados não tem URL, o que existe é um script back-end que acessa um banco e então o banco via TCP, retorna os dados para o script, o script devolve para o output e este output é baixado para o navegador do usuário que fez a requisição HTTP relacionada.

Comment: Foi uma maneira de expressar cara, lógico que ele vai ter que processar a informação do banco seja com PHP, ou qualquer outra linguagem, o que eu quis dizer é que ali vem o retorno do banco com a informação do email.

Comment: Eu entendi a sugestão @Leandro desse jeito é interessante também, mas é o seu script não marca o campo como inválido.

Comment: Opa @JeanFreitas refiz a lógica aqui e editei a resposta, se vc quiser tentar ainda.